# Command Line Java Project Helpers/Generators

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm developing, compiling, and running my Java project from the Ubuntu command line. The IDE I was using gave me helpers that generated basic project files for me.

Is there something similar available for the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Maven, but you have to define simple `pom.xml` first.
Here you can find details: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

@EDIT:
Here is better tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: yup, just about to post that. For templated projects from the command line maven is the way to go.